# apache benchmark on HipHop for PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, hiphop

Recently I've done a benchmark on HipHop for PHP with Apache Benchmark (ab).

I expected the result HipHop for PHP run faster than normal apache2 web server, but it turned out the other way.

I use this script to test the server,

```
<?php
  $i=0;
  while($i < 1000000){
    echo 'Welcome to HipHop for PHP<br />';
    $i++;
  }
?>
```

and I use this ab command to benchmark:

```
ab -n 500 -c 5 [URL]
```

and I use this command to compile:

hphp/hphp hiphop1.php -k 1 -l 3

The benchmark result for the apache2 server:

```
kiddo@kiddo-VirtualBox:~/dev/hiphop-php/doc$ ab -n 500 -c 5 http://localhost/hiphop1.php
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Finished 500 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.2.16
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /hiphop1.php
Document Length:        31000000 bytes

Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   71.024 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      15500095500 bytes
HTML transferred:       15500000000 bytes
Requests per second:    7.04 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       710.240 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       142.048 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          213122.37 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.9      0      19
Processing:   505  708  61.1    694     960
Waiting:        0    0   3.3      0      67
Total:        505  708  61.1    695     960

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    695
  66%    714
  75%    729
  80%    736
  90%    781
  95%    857
  98%    898
  99%    938
 100%    960 (longest request)
```

and the benchmark for HipHop for PHP:

```
kiddo@kiddo-VirtualBox:~/dev/hiphop-php/doc$ ab -n 500 -c 5 http://localhost:8080/hiphop1.php
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Finished 500 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /hiphop1.php
Document Length:        31000000 bytes

Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   294.546 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      15500052500 bytes
HTML transferred:       15500000000 bytes
Requests per second:    1.70 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2945.455 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       589.091 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          51390.26 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   1.6      0      20
Processing:  1515 2941 579.7   2919    4734
Waiting:     1452 2626 532.5   2609    4135
Total:       1515 2941 579.7   2919    4734

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   2919
  66%   3147
  75%   3334
  80%   3448
  90%   3704
  95%   3937
  98%   4223
  99%   4394
 100%   4734 (longest request)
```

The question is, why HipHop run slower in my benchmark?

is there anything wrong with the script test?

Comment: Servers (especially the output buffer) may be configured differently. If buffer is too small more input/output operations is required.

Comment: Your test code is far from a typical web-app workload.  Modern web apps will be doing a lot of object instantization, database IO, user input processing, etc.  All your code is testing is looping and text output.  It's entirely possible that hiphop is faster under typical real-world usage but slower in one or two very specific cases.

Comment: Any suggestion in benchmarking web application? especially HipHop for PHP? I don't know how to make a test case for benchmarking web server

Comment: I've got the result I want by using bench.php from php official development repository. I use ab to benchmark, but I only get the execution time. How can I get the cpu and memory usage?

Comment: you can get CPU load with a script

Comment: I also wouldn't run the benchmark on the same machine of the application under test.

Answer (score 3):

It is a common misconception that PHP hip-hop speeds up PHP code execution. It doesn't necessarily. Facebook developed it because their whole platform is built into a couple of PHP files, and those files are executed so frequently and are so massive that it would be inefficient to use pure PHP.

using Hip-Hop is just adding a step to the execution of PHP, you should never use PHP Hip-Hop for 'Simple' Code like that.

> > Also, PHP executes some functions that are natively executed in C+ with their PHP script.